# Package error while trying to upgrade mysql-server

Tags: upgrade, apt, mysql

I am trying to upgrate mysql 5.1 to version 5.5
Since official ubuntu repositories do not provide 5.5, I've decided to go with [Dotdeb](http://www.dotdeb.org/2011/12/19/mysql-5-5-19/) repository.

When I've updated the package information and typed in `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` it removed my mysql 5.1 but does not want to install 5.5, giving this error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.19-1~dotdeb.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mysql', which is also in package mysql-client-core-5.1 5.1.54-1ubuntu4
```

Do you have any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I'm partly guessing here, but it looks like Ubuntu have split some of `mysql-client` into a `mysql-client-core` package, which doesn't exist on Debian. So possibly the Dotdeb package dependencies/conflicts don't know about the `mysql-client-core` package and it hasn't removed it.

You could try

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-client-core-5.1
```

and try again. The files that you remove with this command should be replaced by the new `mysql-client` you're about to install (`mysql-server` will depend on it and install it automatically)

Obviously, tread carefully, if the command above suddenly wants to remove 200 other packages, don't do it, and report back here with more info about the results (edit your original question).